# Splitting interleaved data into separate channels' np.arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a binary file, that contains interleaved data; here is a Python script that will generate an example of it:

`test-np-array-il-split-01.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# (also works with python3)

# generate a test binary file with interleaved floats

thebinfilename = "il3ch.binfile"

import struct

# https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html :  "=" native; "<" little-endian; ">" big-endian
with open(thebinfilename, 'wb') as f:
  for ix in range(10):
    decremain = ix/100.0;
    for ic in range(3):
      thischannum = ic+1 + decremain;
      print(thischannum)
      f.write(struct.pack("=f", thischannum))
```

Basically, just run `python test-np-array-il-split-01.py`, and you will get a binary file `il3ch.binfile` in the same directory. This file basically has this sequence of floating numbers:

> 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.01, 2.01, 3.01, 1.02, 2.02, 3.02, 1.03, 2.03, 3.03, 1.04, 2.04, 3.04, 1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 1.06, 2.06, 3.06, 1.07, 2.07, 3.07, 1.08, 2.08, 3.08, 1.09, 2.09, 3.09

... stored as binary floats.

Basically, I want to obtain the individual channel data as separate numpy arrays, where the channels would be:

- Ch1: 1.0, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, ...
- Ch2: 2.0, 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04, ...
- Ch3: 3.0, 3.01, 3.02, 3.03, 3.04, ...

So, I've tried to write the following script (place it in the same folder as `test-np-array-il-split-01.py` and `il3ch.binfile`):

`test-np-array-il-split-02.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# (also works with python3)

# read a test binary file with interleaved floats

thebinfilename = "il3ch.binfile"

import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype( [ ('CH1', '<f4'), ('CH2', '<f4'), ('CH3', '<f4') ] )
bin_np_arr = np.fromfile(thebinfilename, dtype=dt)

print(bin_np_arr.shape) # (10,)
print(bin_np_arr)
# [(1.  , 2.  , 3.  ) (1.01, 2.01, 3.01) (1.02, 2.02, 3.02)
#  (1.03, 2.03, 3.03) (1.04, 2.04, 3.04) (1.05, 2.05, 3.05)
#  (1.06, 2.06, 3.06) (1.07, 2.07, 3.07) (1.08, 2.08, 3.08)
#  (1.09, 2.09, 3.09)]

ch1, ch2, ch3 = bin_np_arr[:][0], bin_np_arr[:][1], bin_np_arr[:][2]

print(ch1) # (1., 2., 3.) # -> however, I want 1.0, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03 ... etc here!
```

So, the good thing is that by using the `np.dtype` specification, I can impose a sort of a structure that is in the data - however, as output I get np.array of (CH1, CH2, CH3) tuples, and I really cannot tell what do I need to do, to split this np.array.

So my question is: how can I split the `bin_np_arr` np.array into three separate np.arrays, which will correspond to the individual channel data? Also, should I read in the `bin_np_arr` differently from file (e.g. so it has a different `.shape`), so its more amenable to this kind of a "per-channel" split?

Comment: You can get each channel as `bin_np_arr['CH1']`, `bin_np_arr['CH2']` and `bin_np_arr['CH3']`.

Comment: Many thanks @jdehesa - works great! Feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), you can access the arrays corresponding to each field with the syntax `['<field name>']`. In your case, you can simply do:

```
ch1, ch2, ch3 = bin_np_arr['CH1'], bin_np_arr['CH2'] and bin_np_arr['CH3']
```